# Custom Web Part not pushing down next web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I wrote a custom web part which displays an image on the top right of a div in order to look like this ...

https://ibb.co/1GfzTPj

It works fine.

But when I add the web part to my SPO tenant it looks like this ...

https://ibb.co/b72mvzq

Any ideas why its not pushing down the next section?

Thanks
P

```
.theContainer{
    /*width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;*/
    margin: 20px;
}
```

.theText
{

```
border:5px solid Red;
padding:50px;
position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
```

}

.theImage{
z-index: 9;
margin: 0px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}

```
<div class="theContainer">

    <div class='theText'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
    </div>
    <div class='theImage'>
        <img src='.\quotes.png' height='55' width='55'>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: BTW if I set the height of the theContainer to 200px it will push the next web part down but I will never know how much it should push it down as the text contents may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I read the title of this post I thought, "I bet he's using absolute positioning".

Absolute positioning detaches the elements from normal page flow. So yeah other elements will render over the top of it. Also it looks like you've set `theImage` and `theText` to render in the exact same location.

Comment: Hi Derek is there anything that I can do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: remove the absolute positioning and find another way to achieve the layout you're looking for.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/simple-and-nice-blockquote-styling/

Comment: Thanks Derek for the help!